# Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association :image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть три модели:

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lessons, as: :image
end

class Cover < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lessons, as: :image
end

class Background < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lessons, as: :image
end
```

Ну и модель Lesson, соответственно:

```
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :image, polymorphic: true
end
```

В итоге я получаю ошибку:

> Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association :image

Ошибка вызвана этим кодом:

```
Course.all.joins(groups: { lessons: :image })
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: в какой момент вы получаете ошибку?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman добавил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это потому, что ассоциация `belongs_to :image, polymorphic: true` полиморфна и может указывать на вообще любые ActiveRecord'овые модели.

Поэтому чтобы сделать `JOIN` на неё (гипотетически) в общем случае нужно приделать по строчке такого вида:

```
INNER JOIN things ON lessons.image_id = things.id AND lessons.image_type = "Thing"
```

...для **каждой модели** (на примере `Thing`). А ORM'ке потом разгребаться с гигантским числом колонок в result set'е, выбирая для каждой строчки то, что совпало.

### Это безумие. И оно не реализовано.

---

А у вас, скорее всего, фиаско в дизайне и вам был нужен [Single Table Inheritance](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance), модели которого размещаются в одной таблице и таки поддаются `JOIN`'у без приключений.

А полиморфом лучше пользоваться только в случае крайней необходимости.

Comment: Очень интересно про STI было почитать. Благодарю :)

Comment: @ а можете привести что-нибудь в пример "крайней необходимости", пожалуйста? Чтобы я хотя бы приблизительно знал про эту "грань".

Comment: @Colibri скажем, какой-нибудь обобщенный плагин для добавления комментариев к любой модели. И даже там далеко не во всех ситуациях полиморф будет уместен. И вообще, он не ложится на реляционную модель, РСУБД не может гарантировать его согласованность (consistency), поэтому проще "избегать любой ценой".